# PHP convering date format before mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am having problems with inserting records to mysql. The records I have are from a different website (downloaded records) in .CSV and the dates are in "2/12/2015" format. I learned that PHP or Mysql only accepts or understands "YYYY-MM-DD" format or even "YYYYMMDD".

How can I format the dates before including them in the mysql query string? How can I change or convert the arrangement "2/12/2015" and turn it into "2015-2-12"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use date() and strtotime() functions:

```
$date = strtotime("2/12/2015");
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: sorry missed strtotime() on first post, just updated it

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I tried searching on the web but was unlucky with keywords. I will try this now

Comment: This one worked for me so far :)

Answer (score 2):

Using explicit date formats:

```
$dateValue = '2/12/2015';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', $dateValue );
$dateValue = $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

$dateValue holds the converted date

Comment: Thanks William, may I ask what the difference in outcome is between your suggestion and Gabriel's? Please forgive me for saying but if both produce the same output I might go with Gabriel's as it's easier to remember for a noob like me :D

Comment: The main difference is the date format supplied here vs. letting PHP determine the format and convert to an unix timestamp. strtotime http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php . Both are accurate implementations given your requirements it is up to you. It is just my preference to define the expected input format in addition to the output and avoid strtotime unless that is the output I desire: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/how-i-learned-stop-using-strtotime-and-love-php-datetime

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't figure this out but the date being returned here seem to be different date, the format worked though :(

Comment: The output is 2015-12-02 which is the same date as the input just in a different format. If there's something you don't understand feel free to start your own topic :)

Comment: Yes sorry, when I tried it I was using '2/12/2015' and the output I was getting was '2014-4-7'. The format was correct but the date was becoming incorrect. Anyway I will attempt to use this again as it looks more complete